# Nhibernate prevent update before delete

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, self-reference

I have a self referencing object Cycle:

```cs
public class Cycle
{
    public Cycle()
    {
        ParentCycle = this;
        ChildCycles = new List<Cycle>{this};
    }

    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Cycle ParentCycle { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Cycle> ChildCycles { get; set; }
    public virtual int Version { get; set; }
}
```

With the following mapping:

```cs
public class CycleMap : ClassMap<Cycle>
{
    public CycleMap()
    {
        Table("Cycle");

        Id(x => x.Id).Column("CycleID");
        References(x => x.ParentCycle).Column("ParentCycleID").Not.Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.ChildCycles).KeyColumn("ParentCycleID").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Inverse();

        Version(x => x.Version);
    }
}
```

I run the following test code:

```cs
var parentCycle = new Cycle();

session.Save(parentCycle);
session.Flush();

session.Delete(parentCycle);
session.Flush();
```

The creation of the cycle works, but when I try to delete the cycle, I have 2 problems:

- Before the delete statement, NHibernate does an update statement to set the ParentCycle to NULL. However this property is not nullable, because if the cycle does not have a parent it references to himself.
- When I make the property nullable another problem occurs. Nhibernate does the update which now succeeds but during this update it does not increment the version number. This is a problem for our auditing system. With every update the version should be incremented.

I'm wondering if anyone else had the same problems, the ideal solution would be to stop the update because it is unnecessary. But I cannot seem to achieve this.

#### Github

I made my test code available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Dommicentl/NHibernateTest)

Answer (score 0):

It should be easily possible, with setting called **`inverse="true"`**

```
public CycleMap()
{
    ...
    HasMany(x => x.ChildCycles)
        .KeyColumn("ParentCycleID")
         // the setting, instructing NHibernate that other end will care...
        .Inverse()
        .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    ...
```

The point is, if NHibernate knows, that the other end (the inversed one) is taking care about the relationship, it does not have to issue

- update (with null)
- delete

The deep description of the `inverse="true"` could be found here *(I would really suggest to read through, it is really well structured overview, still valid for NHibernate)*:

#### [`inverse = “true”` example and explanation by mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/inverse-true-example-and-explanation/)

Comment: Yes, I already tried that. In fact my original mapping had the inverse set, but it still does the update.

Comment: What we need, is to be sure that we delete object from collection which is bound to session. The cascade will then iterate all removed objects, and if they are mapped with inverse, they will be deleted

Comment: Yes I understand why it wants to do the update, however it isn't nessecary when the record in question is already flagged to be deleted. Also why doesn't he increment the version when updating?

Comment: With versioning I am not sure, usually I do have UpdateDate on every object with a Version. Because this property is during any operation changed, the version is of course incremented... NOT sure about situations, when the versioned entity is not "UPDATE"d at all... Other words. AND - If you want delete one entity from collection, and If you have delete orphan... NHiberante will do it properly. The order should be 1) load parent. 2) find child 3) remove child from collection 4) call Flush() .. all will be persited as expected

Comment: By the way, how can you have **NOT NULL** Parent reference? There must be a root parent. And such should have NULL instead of its parent. Cascading in the world without NULLable parent... could be very unpredictable... I'd say. I am trying to say, that maybe you could re-evaluate the approach. And it could help and simplify even this scenario... Nullable parent seem to be as a **the** way... Just a note ;)

Comment: The root parent references itself. I do not like it either but it was necessary for legacy compatibility.